# Is there equivalent for `blendFunci` in WebGL 1?

Tags: three.js, webgl, shader

I'm working on WebGL 1 project. I need to use `gl_FragData[0]` and `gl_FragData[1]` in customized fragment shader. How can I set blendFunction for `gl_FragData[1]`. I think OpenGL uses `glBlendFunci`. for ex, `glBlendFunc(1, gl.ONE, gl.ONE)`. How can I do this in WebGL?

Comment: no there is no equivalent

Comment: `@gman` how can I use different blending function for `gl_FragData[0]` and `gl_FragData[1]`?

Comment: you can't .  you can read 2 textures, blend them inside the shader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `glBlendFunci` equivalent in WebGL1. To do custom blending the normal solution is to take 2 textures in, blend them in a shader, and output to a new texture

```
 uniform sampler2D t1;
 uniform sampler2D t2;

 void main() {
   gl_FragColor = someOperation(t1, t2);
 }
```

To do more than one would just be the same thing repeated as in

```
 uniform sampler2D t1;
 uniform sampler2D t2;
 uniform sampler2D t3;
 uniform sampler2D t4;

 void main() {
   gl_FragData[0] = someOperation(t1, t2);
   gl_FragData[1] = someOperation(t3, t4);
 }
```